# Exending JavaFX Classes in Clojure with gen-class

Tags: javafx, clojure, clojure-java-interop

I write desktop apps. Lately I have been using JavaFX for the GUI portion. I **love** Clojure but have run into problems doing some slightly complex things.

Many customizations of the UI (adding check boxs to a group of list items, changing the colors of alternating rows in a table, setting icons in a tree view, etc.) require extending JavaFX classes though. In my particular case, I've been trying to extend `javafx.scene.control.Cell` or one of it's derivatives.

I can't figure out how to do this in Clojure. A few days ago, I posted a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43002816/javafx-font-face-dialog-in-clojure) regarding how to extend a `TextFieldListCell`, but that received little attention. After a few more days of investigation, it seems that the problem is more general in the interop between Clojure and JavaFX. An [issue](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1315?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#issue-tabs) was raised in the Clojure Google group a few years ago, but the resulting patch does not seem to work for my case.
All of my attempts to extend such a class result in a `ExceptionInInitializerError` caused by the toolkit not being initialized when the `gen-class` or `proxy` are compiled in Clojure.

I've come up with a workaround where I just implement the extended class in Java and import it into the Clojure project. It works, but it's ugly.

Is there a general way to extend such JavaFX classes in Clojure? For example,
how would the following Java class, which extends `javafx.scene.control.ListCell`, be written in Clojure.

```java
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;

public class FontFaceListCell extends ListCell<String> {
    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
        } else {
            setFont(Font.font(item, 16.0d));
            setText(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, after playing with this for like 20 minutes, I realized I can't even initialize a `ListCell` using IntelliJ. I get `NoClassDefFoundError Could not initialize class javafx.scene.control.ListCell`. Are you even able to do that?

Comment: @Carcigenticate: Yes, I can do that in both Java and Clojure (in Cursive) in IntelliJ. Just can't subclass it.

Comment: There is an fn-fx clojure slack group that might be able to help you. fn-fx is a library that wraps JavaFX, so looking at the source might help too.